# How to uniquely identify an image chosen by UIImagePicker?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I searched the web and didn't find the answer, so I thought I give it one last shot here.
In my app the user has the possibility to choose images from the photo library. I don't want the user to be able to choose the same picture twice, so I am searching for a way to identify an image and to compare it to the already chosen ones. As far as I know, one is not able to get the image-URL or any other identifier for an image from the library, so I am a bit stuck. One (perhaps) possible way I thought of is to compare MD5-Checksums, but I think this is to expensive.

So thanks for your help in advance and please excuse my rusty English.

Muckz

Answer (score 2):

Use the imagePickerController delegate. Here is a sample code,

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc] init];
image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
//store the image
//comparision code

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's actually very slow, MD5-Checksums are probably the best method. This way you don't need to keep on memory all previously selected images to be able to compare. You just need to keep around its checksums.

Another possibility can be to choose randomly a few pixels and save its positions and color values. Then, when a new pict is selected, you can verify that previously saved pixel/colors doesn't match. It's possible that this method fails, but it's probably good enough and fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [UIImagePickerControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html) protocol, there is a method `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`. When this method is called, store the info NSDictionary in an array (maybe in your App Delegate). If another image is picked, compare the selected NSDictionary with the previous ones you stored using `isEqualToDictionary:`. <strike>No two images will have the same metadata.</strike> (Metadata is only available for newly captured media.)

Comment: I always thought that the metadata is only provided for videos, not for images. This should then work from iPhone SDK 3.2 upwards?

Comment: You are correct. Comparing the dictionaries will still work, though.

Answer (score 0):

Put your Image into an NSMutableArray then when the user select another time check if the selection is into the array...

Comment: So it is possible to compare two images to each over? That I didn't thought of that...

Comment: see KingofBliss's answer it's better

Answer (score -1):

If you have a pointer to the ImageView's then a really Quick and cheap cheap way of doing this would be to set the `.tag` of the `UIImageView` to 1 when its been selected then check it with `if(UIImageView.tag)`

Comment: wow, that was fast ;-) But I think you misunderstood me, sorry that I didn't make it clearer. It is ok, that the user chooses multiple images, but I don't want him to be able to choose the same image twice. A little more background: all choosen images get added to a list, which later gets processed and I don't want an image to appear in that list twice.